# How to use libumem to find heap corruption, without relying on a 'core' file?

Tags: c++, memory, solaris, libumem

I want to know how to use libumem on solaris. If I follow http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/3malloc/umem_debug/ and start the process with all the options, how will I get the output?

Can I get a text file of the results?

I have used wdb on HP-UX for the same. This generates a text file after the program exits, that I can analyze later. Can I do that same for libumem?

Note: This is a remote debugging, I will not have access to the system until afterwards.

Comment: I am using Solaris 9 for now, so the Dtrace won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a core file of the process before it exits and examine the code with mdb later. One way to generate that core file at the right moment could be a dtrace script that will trigger the gcore just when exit is called.

Comment: Thanks jlliagre, can you provide me a pointer to where I should begin looking for such a script? (other that another q on stackoverflow ofcourse!)

Comment: Sorry, clarifying that I am on Solaris 9 for now.

Comment: With Solaris 9, you might use an interposition library to intercept the exit call an run gcore there.

Answer (score 0):

I think libumem will generate a core when things goes wrong , you can analyze this core using mdb , certain commands like ::umem_status , umem_verify will help you in finding the corruption